# Meaning of "even as"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Anjou and Maine both given unto the French!
>   Cold news for me; for I had hope of France,
>   Even as I have of fertile England's soil.
>   (2H6 I.i.236)

What does *even as* mean in this verse?

I think it is a marker for some sort of simultaneity, but am not quite sure that it is so.

Comment: "Even as" is old English for "Just as". So, "Even as I have of fertile England's soil." basically means in your context "Just as I have hope for England's fertile soil."

Comment: I'd read it as 'just like' (= 'in exactly the same way as') here, though it can have the sense 'at exactly the same time that': _Early one morning just as the sun was shining . . ._

Comment: the rephrasing works because both *even* and *just* have a pragmatic function of sorts, focusing attention on the comparison. my [comments](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140731/is-there-a-rule-or-something-that-explain-where-to-put-even/140813#140813) at another question about **even** might be useful here. (i'm assuming the current usage of **even** was the same in Shakespeare's time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even - (*archaic*) Exactly, just, fully.

> I fulfilled my instructions even as I had promised.
>   
>   You are leaving tonight? — Even so.
>   
>   This is my commandment, that ye love one another, even as I have loved you.

PS: Please do some research before asking.

Answer (score 1):

That's a more poetic way of stating:

```
My hope for France was equal to my hope for England's soil.
```

Equal to in quality, character, time etc. are all implied

Answer (score -1):

EVEN AS is used for two tasks happening at the same time.

Example;  crowd was protesting outside hall, Even as minister was delivering speech.

This sentence may be rewritten as followings;                                                crowd was protesting outside hall, at the same time when minister was delivering speech.

EVEN AS is frequently used in English Newspapers to mean; the same way as ,  Example; I speak english, Even as I speak my native language.

Comment: This answer has too many errors in spelling, syntax, punctuation, and formatting to be a useful response to the almost two-year-old question asked here. And in any case, the accepted answer (also from almost two years ago) provides a reference-based (rather than ad hoc or anecdotal) answer that fully resolves OP's question.

Comment: Can any one tell me what errors are in this explanation given by me?