# What does "even" mean in this statement?

Tags: grammar

I haven't understood what *even* means here:

```
How do you even know that?
```

and what's the difference with the following?

```
How do you know that?
```

Comment: It's an intensifier.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a rule or pointer explaining where to put '\_even'\_ in a sentence?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140731/is-there-a-rule-or-pointer-explaining-where-to-put-even-in-a-sentence)

Comment: @Robusto In general it's a scalar focus particle. This usage is certainly intensifying (almost equivalent to an introductory 'Wow!'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Whatever you call it, I still think it acts as an intensifier in that sentence.

Comment: Agreed (though it's intensifying the statement here, not the verb _know_). It's a different usage from that in 'How could you even _think_ that?', where (scalar) comparison with implied other verbs (firmly believe / say / write) makes sense. I'm saying it's rather an unusual usage in OP's example.

Comment: Is this actually only a part of what you intend the sentence to be, say 'How do you even know that there is a Father Christmas?' If so, there will be contextual scalarity (eg the previous sentence could be 'Do you think Father Christmas will come before 3 o'clock tomorrow?')

Answer (score 1):

the word "even" is used in this to show somewhat an act of surprise.

e.g "I can't believe your amount of knowledge, how'd you even know that?"

The difference between the two statements are the use of expressions. The word "even" provides a more stressed toned rather than simply questioning their comprehension.

Comment: I agree. An unusual pragmatic usage (I can't find it listed in most dictionaries I've looked in).

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a term of wonderment that I can't believe you knew that rather than a simple question asking for a source

Comment: This is (to me) the right answer. The asker has no interest in how the other person knows that. "How do you even know that?" is the same as "I really, really, really, never imagined that you would know that". The simple "How do you know that?" (without any fancy intonation on 'you') is a straight forward request.

Answer (score 0):

This usage is picked up on in the [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=even)

> **even** word added to a sentence when you want to stress something
>   hysterically just to sound angrier.
>
> 'Why are you EVEN trying it?'
>
> 'What are you EVEN doing here?'

Though both these examples strongly suggest other verbs with implications even more laughable (as required by stricter definitions in other dictionaries), the loose definition given here works with say

> 'How do you even know that?'

where one might well ask 'Know it as opposed to . . . ?

Comment: I don't really see how this is anything other than a regular use of scalar *even* but with only one other alternative on the scale: the negation of the asserted one (with VP focus).  If the only other alternative is the negative you will get the amazement reading for free.

Comment: That isn't the way E J Bakker, in [Linguistics and Formulas in Homer: Scalarity ...](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=_1aOsmDhHTQC&pg=PA27&lpg=PA27&dq=%22scalar+particle%22+even&source=bl&ots=dEgxx1GzV0&sig=ELMdEYTAzqT2LJDUdvhhR3SdfAc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=jZupVL-2KsHxatmwguAJ&ved=0CF4Q6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=%22scalar%20particle%22%20even&f=false) looks at scalarity in language. Perhaps you can find an author supporting your view?

Comment: That's a big book, and I can't see all of it through Google Books, but is there a place where this particular kind of sentence is discussed? I was basing my suggestion on Rooth 1992 (Natural Language Semantics) which is a fairly standard account, but he doesn't talk about that exact case either, but I don't see how it couldn't be applied to it.

Comment: _What are you even doing here?_ means _You shouldn't be here_ according to this Facebook site. https://www.facebook.com/pages/The-what-are-you-even-doing-here-look/105134219529263?sk=info&tab=page_info Giving rise to _Facebook is even a source?_ meaning _Facebook is not a source_

Comment: In this article, [Anyone for non-scalarity?](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=7212896&fileId=S1360674309990402)
Patrick J. Duffley and Pierre Larrivée explore whether the determiner _any_ should be considered to have scalar meaning in all or just some of its usages. Certainly the promiscuous _even_ hasn't: 'It's certainly meretricious. _Meritorious_, even.' (used informally as a correction marker) Assuming OP isn't omitting vital context here, I'd say it's simpler to view this usage of _even_ as an amazement marker ('How _on earth_ do you know that?').